# Can Google Nexus Player process input video from a simple HDMI and then output processed video further?

Tags: android, video-processing, nexus-player

So is it possible that I get input video to Google Nexus Player, process it in some way and then further (processed) send it to output, like a TV?

Comment: I am fairly certain that we do not have access to the HDMI signal.

Comment: Too sad. I was hoping to get an option of handling my TV signal and use NP as an STB kind of or at least smartTV addon.